# SSRS report with detail data

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am trying to create a chart in SSRS which shows detail data.
I need to graphically show the time of day that a problem was detected and the time that day when it was reported.

I am concerned that this isn't possible based on my efforts and on this statement from the MSFT documentation:
[Charts do not display detail data.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/charts-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#GroupsInChart)

The issue is that I don't want to group my data into categories, the grouping will be done visually by the user when they look at all of the report data. (There could be 1000+ data points in a given day)

Here's a 10 line example:

> row #   Detected              Reported
>   1       12/13/2019 08:32:26   12/13/2019 09:01:07
>   2       12/13/2019 09:01:46   12/13/2019 09:10:48
>   3       12/13/2019 09:02:49   12/13/2019 09:10:30
>   4       12/13/2019 09:11:15   12/13/2019 09:19:17
>   5       12/13/2019 09:23:59   12/13/2019 09:31:11
>   6       12/13/2019 09:27:38   12/13/2019 10:25:21
>   7       12/13/2019 10:04:02   12/13/2019 10:12:35
>   8       12/13/2019 10:04:05   12/13/2019 10:15:46
>   9       12/13/2019 10:04:05   12/13/2019 10:20:10
>   10      12/13/2019 10:04:08   12/13/2019 10:18:00

What I want seems simple enough, and can be done easily in Excel.
I want to provide a chart for the users to directly access from SSRS - I'd prefer *not* to write an Excel macro that creates a chart from the data (and it is unclear to me if I could get SSRS to do this given my organization's security settings).

The y-axis will contain the time of day (8 AM to 5 PM)
The x-axis is an ordered set of times (by row number) of two times (time detected and time reported)
The data points are the time periods (two for each number on the x-axis plotted at the y-axis time of day)

Example image showing what I want:
[image]

Comment: I don't see why you can't do this in a chart - you seem to already know what you need.  The MSDN line you quote seems to be more of a guideline than hard rule.

Comment: @HannoverFist I see how to add Category groups (rows) and Series groups (columns) but it requires an aggregate function. Which I don't want to specify... hopefully I'm just missing something easy.

Comment: Actually the Series and Category both use the X-axis. You can use MAX(Reported) for the Y value.